# ifstream wont read all integer

Tags: c++, fstream

When i read TestData.txt file it gives me wrong output. What am i doing wrong.  I am using int array so i can do MergeSort after saving data into array.

```
TestData.txt
-------------------
31791   564974  477059  269094  972335
739154  206345  634644  227684  398536
910177  507975  589785  67117   395140
598829  372499  364165  450187  996527
700285  263407  918021  661467  457544
656297  846316  221731  240676  68287
913 141702  845802  477617  109824

{
int myArray[1000];
     int i;
    //reading givin data 
    const char* filename= "TestData.txt";   
    ifstream file(filename);
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        for(i = 0; i <=999; ++i)
        {
            file >> myArray[i];//storing data to array


        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the wrong output and where does it come from?

Comment: You are attempting to read 1000 entries from the file. Does it contain that many numbers?

Comment: Your input code is perhaps OK, the problem is with your output code, or with the code inbetween.

Comment: How many numbers were printed correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Need to check if you ifstream is `end of file`, in that case you get garbage value from out of the file bound.

With One modification, the code would be OK.

Change:

```
   for(i = 0; i <=999; ++i)
```

to:

```
   for(i = 0; i <=999 && !file.eof(); ++i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading 1000 enties from your file which contains clearly less than 1000 integers.
The first values of your array must be correct, but after you reach the end of your file the operator>> will not ready anything.

For example here is one way to write it:

```
const char* filename= "TestData.txt";   

std::vector<int> myArray;
std::ifstream file(filename);
if(file.is_open())
{   
    int v;
    while(file >> v) {
        myArray.push_back(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: The standard method for reading a file is: `while (file >> v) {my_array.pushback(v);}`.  Or you could search Stack Overflow for "c++ iterator ifstream vector" to use an iterator to do this for you.

Answer (score -3):

int if I'm not wrong can keep data from -32768 to 32767.
So if u have bigger values than that (which you have, from your source file), you won't have the results you are expecting.

btw, it would be nice to know also what output you are getting.

Comment: Those are *minimum* requirements on `int`. Most compilers let you have bigger numbers in an `int`.

Comment: right but... still, if the code seems to be legit, it's the only thing I can think about...

Comment: The error is likely to be in the code he hasn't posted. All too common.